# Right aligned column on Bootstrap with an unordered list with no wrapping text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I do not want the lines to overflow to next line. ie the line details should be on the sameline. So far I have tried this. But obviously not correct.
[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-right">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Address: DetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetails</li>
            <li>Telephone: DetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetails</li>
            <li>Fax: DetailsDetailsDetails</li>
            <li>Email: DetailsDetailsDetails</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the codeply I have tried: https://www.codeply.com/go/3kyZUPbLoR

Comment: Now the line details are showing up in separate lines itself right ?

Comment: What do you want the desired result to be if the line is longer than its parent container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float-right` and `text-nowrap` on the list items...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <ul class="list-unstyled float-right">
                <li class="text-nowrap">Line1: DetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetails</li>
                <li class="text-nowrap">Line2: DetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetailsDetails</li>
                <li class="text-nowrap">Line3: DetailsDetailsDetails</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/OZaLa2kP1L

Answer (score 0):

How about using `<dl>` with flexbox?

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Address:</dt>
            <dd>Address here</dd>
            <dt>Telephone:</dt>
            <dd>123456</dd>
            <dt>Email:</dt>
            <dd>email@email.com</dd>
            <dt>Fax:</dt>
            <dd>123454</dd>
        </dl>   
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
dl.dl-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 75%;
    flex: 0 1 40%;
}

dl.dl-horizontal dt,
dl.dl-horizontal dd {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-left: .25rem solid red;
}

dl.dl-horizontal dt {
    flex: 0 0 40%;
}

dl.dl-horizontal dd {
    flex: 0 0 60%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The styles `flex: 0 0 40%` on **dt** and `flex: 0 0 60%` on **dd** are mainly to make sure one **dt** and **dd** per line. They're also styled to display ellipsis when overflowing so we're good there.

To make **dl** to float right, instead of using `float:right;`, I wrap the **dl** with a flexbox and set to display its items in reverse order, `flex-row-reverse`. The last thing to do is to set a proper width for the **dl**. You can use `width:WHATEVER_WIDTH;`, or what I used here: `flex: 0 1 WHATEVER_PERCENTAGE%;`.

[image]

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/qu1behny/32/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I had go with the early answer for its less intrusive without the custom styles needed.